# Excel, TRIM Path to 2nd last "/"

Tags: microsoft-excel

**I have following paths:**

Stack/Over/Flow

Super/User

**Formula I have:**

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","|",B2))+1)
```

This currently takes my path in A2, and whatever # I state in B2, trims the path based on the #. So if I have 2 in B2, it will give me flow, and if I put 1 it will give me Over/Flow. Problem is the paths I have are not uniform in length and also doesnt trim the end node. **My Formula is in C2. Number to parse in B2. paths in A2.**

The trick here is to get it to extract the 2nd last node.

**Desired Output**:

Over

Super

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach will allow the extraction of any `/` separated segment based on the value in B2.

First define a name `seq_99`

`seq_99  refers to: =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)`

This creates an array of values `{1;99;198;297;...}`

**NOTE** If any of your segments might be longer, then increase the 99; eg to 999)

Then try this formula:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),B2)
```

Where B2 contains the position of the segment you wish to extract.

If you want to count in reverse, such that

> 1 = last segment
>
> 2 = next to last segment

Then replace B2 with:

```
(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))+2-B2
```

so the formula would look like:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))+2-B2)
```

Here is an example of the formula being used.  Note that with a `2` in Column B, the second from last segment is being returned by the formula:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean define a name? is this a function?

Comment: `Define Name` is an option on the `Defined Names` tab of the Formula bar. A Name can refer to either a location or a formula.  Do an internet search for examples of how to use this feature; just copy the `seq_99` and the formula into the appropriate boxes.

Comment: Which cells am I to define the name to? B2:B1000 (or to my last path name) ?

Comment: @Jonnyboi  I do not understand your question.  I wrote nothing about any defined names other than `seq_99`.  If you want to define another name for your own purposes, you can certainly do that.

Comment: I meant which cell do I do the definition in? All my path names are A2:A22350 , So I am defining seq_99 in B1. 
Next I am using `=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),B2)` in B2. Then replace the 'B2' part of the forumla with `(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))+2-B2` right ?

Comment: @Jonnyboi Again, I don't know what you mean.  You don't "define a name" in a worksheet cell.

Comment: @Jonnyboi  And also, since you have information in column B, according to your original question, I don't think you would want to overwrite that information with the formula.  Where would you get your position information from then?

Comment: Confused with where things are going. I got seq_99 defined. paths in A2:A2250. What goes in B2?  Is this a number I put in here? or your formula?

Comment: @Jonnyboi Look at the screenshot I just posted.  And read up about how to use Names as I have previously commented.  Of course, you could just replace `seq_99` in the formula with `=IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)`, but that would make for a very long formula.

Comment: ah okay, got it now , works! except "2" is giving me the 3rd last segment. I'm guessing this may be because there is no ending '/' in the full path , so its counting the 2nd last as the one after the 2nd '/'?

Comment: @Jonnyboi In your example data, `2` is giving the 2nd to last segment.  If you need an explanation of other behavior, you will have to provide data that exhibits that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",99)),(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))-1)*99+1,99))
```

It will return the second to last:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, it works on some of my paths, not all.. in some cases it returns the 3rd last..in some I got blanks, and some is partial characters

Comment: please give some examples of those that are in error.  @Jonnyboi

Comment: its quite bizarre..trying to figure out why in my paths its not working.. When doing examples it works fine..but my data set getting different returns.

Comment: copy and paste the ones that are not working directly and see if you get the same issue.  Also make sure all the references in those formulas are to the same cell.

Comment: Yes same issue in another sheet. Why sometimes it returns 2 letters instead of full node

Comment: I cannot possibly help without seeing the data.